# Sony SmartWatch Handler fails

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch

I've got this very weird situation. I program my Sony SmartWatch, and use a Handler to schedule tasks. When I activate the app the Handler schedules a task which gets called a few seconds after the app activation.

But the Handler fails when the phone goes to sleep. The thing I don't get is that even though the phone is asleep, my SmartWatch app functions correctly, except for scheduling the mentioned task. As I understand, this means that the smart extension service is actually alive in the phone although the phone is asleep. So why doesn't the Handler work either?

Your help will be much appreciated!

Here is an example of the code:

```
static msgbox(String txt) {
    showBitmap(txtToBitmap(txt));

    // mHandler is global and was created by mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showBitmap(mOriginalBitmap);  // "closes" the message
        }
    }, 3000);  // in 3 seconds the message box will be closed
}
```

Comment: Which handler? Can you post some code

Comment: @weston - Hi, I added an example

Comment: Do you use context in your showBitmap method? I guess your context goes null and you are getting NPE.

Comment: As a work around, and just of interest to see if it makes a difference. Try the AlarmManager

Comment: My context wasn't null. I tried an alarm manager, and it works much better, but sometimes fails the same way.